# MySQL: Оператор LOAD DATA INFILE IGNORE увеличивает поле id даже при ошибке

Tags: php, mysql

Есть такой запрос:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '%s' 
IGNORE INTO TABLE %s 
FIELDS
  TERMINATED BY ',' 
  ENCLOSED BY \"'\" 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Проблема в том что в загружаемом файле часто попадаются значения, которые уже есть в базе и стоят как unique. Когда такая запись встречается, то он не добаляется, но автоинкремент все равно увеличивает значение для вставке следующй записи. То есть, у меня было в таблице:

```
id      string
1       text1
2       text2
...
20      text20
```

Потом я сделал вставку из файла, где все записи кроме 4-х, допустим, были повторениями и получилось:

```
id      string
20      text20
...
500     text25
```

Как сделать так чтобы автоинкремент не увеличивался если произошла ошибка (такое поле уже есть в базе) желательно без временной таблицы? Спасибо.

Comment: как вариант - загружать во временную таблицу, а потом вставлять уже из этой таблицы только те записи, которые отсутствуют

Comment: Хотелось бы это на крайний вариант оставить.

Comment: я только сейчас заметил *желательно без временной таблицы* ))) А чем вас эти id не устраивают? Часто загружаете и много дублирующих полей? Вариант "перед залитием проверять наличие записи" тоже не рассматриваете? Можно поискать заплатки, но это из исходников собирать надо будет - не всегда подходит

Comment: @BOPOH я думал можно поведение мускуля в этой ситуацией какой-то настройкой подкрутить. Если нет, то видимо придется какую-то проверку делать. А не устраивают тем что будет очень много записей, которые кроме того что не по порядку будут идти еще с огромным значениями.

Answer (score 1):

Механизм `AUTO_INCREMENT` не предназначен для создания неразрывных последовательностей. Если важно назначить идентификаторы неразрывно, лучше поправить исходный файл таким образом, чтобы в нем не содержались дублирующие значения. В качестве варианта можно удалить получившийся столбец `id` и создать его по-новой (если операция загрузки разовая).